# How do I print output so that the variables are column aligned?

Tags: php, string

I want to aligning my output in columns. But when I try to do this I always get this:

```
1. FIRSTNAME1      LASTNAME1 
2. FIRSTNAME2     LASTNAME2
3. FIRSTNAME3    LASTNAME3
```

The output I want would be like this:

```
 1. FIRSTNAME1          LASTNAME1   D. 
 2. FIRSTNAME2          LASTNAME2   D.
 3. FIRSTNAME3          LASTNAME3   D.
```

This is the code that I use:

```
$log  = $lastname."    ".$firstname.PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents('logs/'.date("Y-m-d").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Please add some more information regarding this issue which would help us to tackle the problem.

Comment: Hi sir @sharvil111, I updated the information with the following output, i put it on the image file so it will be understandable.

Comment: Post the code that generates the output.

Comment: Hi sir @manassehkatz, already put the code on the post.

Comment: Rrj, but obviously the names have all different lengths, haven't they?

Comment: @yivi, yes sir they have different lengths, the one i showed is just for sample.

Comment: You can create a CSV file as an ouput, which can be easy to read & formatted too.

Comment: Hi sir @yivi, the code is helpful, but there is 1 problem sir when i tried to populated the middlename with same process of str_pad(), something went wrong.

i post to the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your names have all different lengths, so if you want your "columns" to be aligned, just concatenating a few spaces won't cut it.

You need to pad that string so that the name + the spaces afterwards always add up to the same number of characters.

Fortunately for you, there is already a function to accomplish that: [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
$log  = strpad($lastname, 16) . ' ' . $firstname . PHP_EOL;
```

Obviously, you need to choose a padding length that makes sense for your data. Otherwise, any longer `$lastname` will mess up your desired output.